# Default selection in dynamic dropdown shiny

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I'm developing a Shiny app with dynamic dropdowns. Right now it works perfectly but in the first screen I need to set both of my two dropdown menus with the "ALL" option, defined by me.

This option masks all my data with a TRUE value and there's no filter applied in the reactive function that loads the data.

I can't write the real code but it's something like this:

SERVER.R

```
dataFiltered <- reactive({

    if(input$selector=="ALL"){
      mask_1=rep(TRUE, data[,.N])
    }
    else{
      mask_1=data$column==input$selector
    }

    data[mask_1]
})

observe({
    updateSelectizeInput(session, 'selector' ,choices = c("ALL",sort(unique(dataFiltered()[, some_column]))))
  })
```

UI.R

```
selectizeInput(inputId = 'selected', label = 'label', choices = NULL, selected = "ALL")
```

When I set the option `selected = "ALL"` it displays by default all data -so far this is what I wanted-, but when I select another option from the dropdown menu it, automatically, reload the data to all instead of my selection.

Any suggestion?

Thanks in advance